# Anova with response dependent on other variables that arent the predictor

Tags: anova, poisson-regression, contingency-tables, manova

I am running into difficulty determining the best way to analyze my data. So, as backgroud I have a dataset containing the variables MONTH, REGION, COUNT, and YEARS. MONTH, REGION, and YEAR and all factors with respective levels. My goal is to determine if COUNT significantly changes through the levels of YEARS. However, my confusion comes from the fact that COUNT is dependent on MONTH and REGION and I am unsure how to incorporate that relationship into the analysis of COUNT on YEARS.

I also belive at some point I should be using a poisson regression as COUNT is not continious, but again I am strugging to know when to incorporate this.

Below is a sample of the dataset for reference.
[image: Sample of dataset]